# Which main steps must be undertaken to successfully port freertos to an embedded platform?

Tags: operating-system, real-time, microcontroller, freertos

I have several years experience with microcontroller programming. Freertos provides the necessary code to port to a set of microcontrollers. I would like to port Freertos to an embedded system which is not supported.

Which main steps have to be undertaken in order to successfully port freertos to another embedded system? (for example: what initialization steps should absolutely be done in port.c etc...) I have read the freertos page about porting, but it is still pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is the page you are referring to http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-porting-guide.html it is vague because each architecture has its own requirements.  For example, is a yield going to be performed synchronously using a trap style instruction, or asynchronously using a pended interrupt, how is interrupt nesting going to be implemented and what support does the hardware give to implement it, etc.  Therefore it would have helped a lot if you said which architecture you wanted to port to, then I might have been able to suggest which port to look at as a reference.

Comment: Target architectures: ARMv7-A and ARMv8-A.

Comment: End goal: port to raspberry pi 3.

Comment: Any idea's to which port I should look as a reference?